# Why are these integrals diffrent

Tags: calculus, integration

Simple question: Why are these different? They should be the same but they are not coming out to the same anti-derivative even though they are the same function.

$$f(x)=\frac{1}{3x+5}$$
$$g(x)=\frac{1}{x+5/3}\frac{1}{3}$$

$$ f(x) = g(x) $$

$$  G(x) = \int_{}^{} g(x) \, dx =  \frac{\ln (x + 5/3)}{3} + C$$
$$  F(x) = \int_{}^{} f(x) \, dx =  \frac{\ln (3x + 5)}{3} + C$$

$$ F(x) \neq G(x) $$
I do not understand why they are any different,g(x) is an equivalent form of f(x) for all x,therefor G(x) should be equal to F(x), but it is not.... There is no reason that I am coming up with that says that They are any different.

Edit:

Forgot about the almighty constant.

$ F(x) = G(x) $ where $C = \frac{\ln(3)}{3}$ for G(x) and $C = 0$ for F(x)

Comment: *Why are these integrals diffrent ?* - They're not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The functions $F(x)$ and $G(x)$ differ by the constant $\frac{\ln 3}{3}$. Antiderivatives are allowed to differ by a constant.

Comment: To clarify the answer:  $C=\frac{\ln(3)}{3}+C'$ for example.

Comment: As the OP wrote them, they both had $C$.

Comment: call one C, the other C' or D or :D

Answer (score 3):

The constants matter. $F(x)$ is $G(x)$ too. In particular,
$$ \ln(3x + 5) = \ln\left( 3\left(x + \frac{5}{3}\right) \right) = \ln(3) + \ln\left( x + \frac{x}{3} \right).$$